# Material SearchView get url query

Tags: java, android

I was using traditional searchview, but I decided to use the material searchview (Google), but I am not able to apply the old rule that I used using webview.

This is my code I was using:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder){

        MenuBuilder menuBuilder = (MenuBuilder) menu;
        menuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    }

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    final SearchView searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchViewAndroidActionBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchViewAndroidActionBar.clearFocus();

            view.loadUrl("https://br-androidtech.blogspot.com/search?q="+query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This is the layout scheme:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleCentered="true">

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Platform.MaterialComponents.Light"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/searchBar">
</com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
```

Can anybody help me?

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks friend, I made the correction, first time using stackoverflow